# Overwhelming probability implies conditionally with overwhelming probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am self-studying Terrence Tao's Topics in Random Matrix Theory.

A sequence of events $F_n$ holds with *overwhelming probability*, if for every fixed $A>0$, there exists a $C_A$ independent of $n$, such that $\mathbb{P}[F_n]\geq 1-C_An^{-A}$.

The statement I struggle to verify is the following (p. 26):

> Suppose that $F_n$ occurs unconditionally with overwhelming probability. Then, it occurs with overwhelming probability conditioning on $E_n$ also, provided that $\mathbb{P}[E_n]\geq cn^{-C}$ for some $c,C>0$ independent of $n$.

This shouldn't be hard, but I'm stuck. Could you help me?

---

**What I tried:**

Right before this statement, he poses the inequality (1.35):
$$
\mathbb{P}[F|E]\leq \frac{\mathbb{P}[F]}{\mathbb{P}[E]}
$$
This way, we could get an upper bound $\mathbb{P}[F|E]\leq c^{-1}n^C\mathbb{P}[F]$, however we want a lower bound.

From (1.32) we also know that:
$$
\mathbb{P}[F]\leq \mathbb{P}[F|E]+\mathbb{P}[\overline{E}]
$$
Therefore, we get $1-C_An^{-A}\leq \mathbb{P}[F|E]+(1-cn^{-C})$.
In other words, $cn^{-C}-C_An^{-A}\leq \mathbb{P}[F|E]$.
But as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the left-hand-side vanishes.

Comment: You want $P[FE] \geq P[E] - P[F^c]$.

Comment: @Michael This gives me $P[F|E]\geq cn^{-C}-C_An^{-A}$, which I already knew (see last line of OP)

Comment: How do you get that?  Perhaps you are using an incorrect definition of conditional probability?

Comment: Using your inequality for conditional probability, $P[F|E]\geq P[E]-P[F^c]$.
We know $P[E]\geq cn^{-C}$ and $P[F]\geq 1-C_An^{-A}$, so $-P[F^c]\geq -C_An^{-A}$.

This should all be correct. I obtain my inequality below "(1.32)" since probabilities are bounded above by 1.
$P[F]=P[F|E]P[E]+P[F|E^c]P[E^c]\leq P[F|E]+P[E^c]$.

Comment: Just divide my first inequality by $P[E]$ and you are done.

Comment: Aha! Your $P[FE]$ is $P[F\cap E]$. I mistook it for $P[F|E]$. Now I get it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This summarizes my comments:
You can show for any events $E, F$ that
$$ P[F\cap E] \geq P[E] - P[F^c]$$
Now if $P[E]>0$ we can divide both sides by $P[E]$ to obtain
$$ P[F|E] \geq 1 - \frac{P[F^c]}{P[E]}$$
The result follows by bounding $P[F_n|E_n]$ using the given bounds on $P[E_n]$ and $P[F_n^c]$ (for an appropriately chosen $A>0$).